# Animated Fit Screen with CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions

My problem is kinda simple.

as you can see in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oJOlIGO/8) I need to make my orange div fit the whole screen with an animated transition using only CSS3

the problem is that just before the animation starts the div changes its place, then animate, this creates an annoying effect that I want to avoid.

here is some code I'm using (you can check for the code source here of course: http://jsbin.com/oJOlIGO/8/edit)

I define a div with the following css:

```
#myDiv{
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
    top: 150px;
    left: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

When I click on a link, I call a js function to change the css

```
function fitScreen (){
    var dom = document.getElementById( 'myDiv' );

    dom.style.position = "fixed";

    dom.style.top = "0";
    dom.style.left = "0";

    dom.style.height = "100%";
    dom.style.width = "100%";

}
```

#### One more thing, I'm aware about the existence of many plugins that cold help me acheive this effect, but I need to do it with only pure js and css

#### Also I have to keep the structure as it is, because in my real project I have a similar configuration that I cannot change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it using a js trick, check the result here: http://jsbin.com/oJOlIGO/10 , what I did is:

- I removed the "transition" from the CSS definition

so now the div css is:

```
#myDiv{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: orange;
    top: 150px;
    left: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

And I've change the js function to be as following:

```
function fitScreen (){
    var dom = document.getElementById( 'myDiv' );
    var rec = dom.getBoundingClientRect();

    // get top and left of the current position
    var pTop = rec.top;
    var pLeft = rec.left;

    dom.style.position = "fixed";
    dom.style.top = pTop + "px";
    dom.style.left = pLeft + "px";

    setTimeout(function(){
        dom.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in-out 0s";

        dom.style.top = "0";
        dom.style.left = "0";

        dom.style.height = "100%";
        dom.style.width = "100%";
    }, 1);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Answer given before user specify that he needs his HTML structure to be unchanged

---

http://jsbin.com/oJOlIGO/3/

This works but I had to change your structure.

**Where was the problem?**

The problem was the

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div id="myDiv">
        <a href="#" onclick="fitScreen();">Click Me</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code, your `#myDiv` had an absolute position relatively to it's parent div. That would just be OK, but changing it's position to `position:fixed`, you cause `#myDiv` to "jump up" because it cannot be relative to it's parent anymore, now it's fixed.

So it has to be changed to

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <a href="#" onclick="fitScreen();">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

And your css from `top: 75px;` to `top: 305px;`

I don't know the rest of the structure, so maybe you'll have to play with your css some more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm only using a dummy sample here, I can't change the structure in my real project

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae That was my fear haha! Write this on the original post! What are your needs? Can you explain a bit more or just post some more code?

Comment: thanks for your support, actually I'm using an embedded code in some web pages, so I need to keep the same structure at least for the moment, my original code is too much to be shared, I can't even think about reducing it :S, but the sharing example is very similar to the real thing

Comment: I've solved the problem, check out my answer for details or visit: http://jsbin.com/oJOlIGO/10 , thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yeah, it was tricky, because without the setTimeout is won't work (even if its just one tiny millisecond)